# Recognizing newline characters in Python

Tags: python, formatting

So I would like to grab stdout from a subprocess and then write the output to a file using python.

The problem I'm having is the stdout from the subprocess loses the formatting, it contains \n's where there are newlines. I would like to write the output to a file with formatting intact, meaning instead of one line containg \n's, the file contains newlines where there are \n's.

Here is my existing code:

```
import os, subprocess
from cStringIO import StringIO

proc = subprocess.Popen('foo.exe', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)

stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]

f=open('fooOut.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(repr(stdout_value)))
f.close()
```

Current File Text: abbbb\nabbbb\naaaaab

What I would like:

abbbb

bbbb

aaaaab

Comment: Search for \\n and replace with \n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `repr()`, ie. just call

```
f.write(stdout_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `repr`?  That turns a object into its representation, which for strings means converting things like `chr(10)` (newline) into `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

The `repr` (which doubles up the "escapes", i.e. backslash characters) is what's causing you to "lose formatting" -- why are you doing that at all?  And btw the `str` call is totally redundant (innocuous, but totally useless -- why have it there?!).